# The value of money in a model economy. Has this been addressed?

Tags: macroeconomics, money-supply

Consider the following question:

"Given a simplified economy which produce and trade some products A,B,C etc... with N agents and a total money supply of M. What will be the price of A, B, C as measured in units of that money?"

It seems to me that this is one of the most fundamental questions in economics and yet I am struggling to find any papers that address it. I guess there may be some [agent based models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-based_computational_economics) out there which address it but I don't know what keywords or phrases to use in a search. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking about is "General Equilibrium with Money", and there is literature on the matter.

To get you started, check out

[**Duffie, D. (1990). Money in general equilibrium theory. in Friedman and Hahn (eds), *Handbook of monetary economics*, vol. 1, 81-100.**](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/21be/5b0b2a688a3f6ecacb016c987f1c08cdc0eb.pdf)

The chapter starts with the sentence

> *This chapter provides conditions for the existence of general **monetary** equilibrium in a simple setting, and discusses the role of
>   money in general equilibrium theory.*